# How to access instance variables in C++ like Objective-C getter and setter

Tags: c++, objective-c, class, operator-overloading

The following is an example:

**In circle.h**

```
class circle
{
    double _radius;
public:
    double getRadius() {return _radius;}
    void setRadius(double r) {_radius=r;} 
}
```

**In main**

```
int main()
{
    circle a;
    cout<<a.getRadius();    // I want to use "a.radius"
    a.setRadius(3.2);       // I want to use "a.radius=3.2"
}
```

So the first question is why we should use get and set function to access instance variables rather than directly access them? The second question is how to do operator overloading to let the function call of get and set looks concise(like what objective-c did)?

Comment: "*why we should use get and set function to access instance variables rather than directly access them?*"  There are book *chapters* on the value of encapsulation.  That's probably beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, the simplest way to make the syntax that you're hoping for available is to just make `_radius` a public member called `radius`:

```
class circle
{
public:
    double radius;
}
```

Now you can use it like so:

```
circle c;
c.radius = 10.0;
```

However, you shouldn't make such decisions based only on how you'd like to write code (or how you might write it in C#). I recommend that you think about the following points for every member:

1. Does it make sense to set the member directly? Perhaps the member is just a private part of the object's state and is affected by other member functions. Consider the following example, where the interface you really want to expose is just a function that increases the size of the `circle`:

   ```
   class circle
   {
   public:
       circle(double radius, double delta = 1.0)
         : radius(radius), delta(delta) { }

       double increaseSize() {
         radius += delta;
         return radius;
       }
   private:
       double radius;
       double delta;
   }
   ```
2. Do you need to enforce an invariant? Consider, perhaps, that you have decided that there can be no such thing as a `circle` with a negative radius. You might want to enforce this by having a member function that checks the given new radius to make sure it is greater than 0.
3. Do you want to provide some different representation of the member through the interface? Maybe you want the `circle` to keep its radius as a member, but the only thing any clients will want to know is its area. You could make `radius` private and then provide a `getArea` function like so:

   ```
   class circle
   {
   public:
       circle(double radius)
         : radius(radius) { }

       double getArea() {
         return PI * radius * radius;
       }
   private:
       double radius;
   }
   ```
4. It's possible that none of the above points apply at the moment, but may do at some point in the future. If you have this foresight, it might be best to provide getter and setter functions now. This ensures that the interface that clients use won't change later on.

As an alternative naming scheme for your getters and setters, it's quite common to simply have two overloaded functions - one for setting and one for getting - like so:

```
class circle
{
public:
    void radius(double); // Set the radius
    double radius();     // Get the radius
private:
    double radius;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In answer to the first question: so your object is encapsulated and you can deal with changed internal representation or the need to modify/update when radius changes.

To the second: you can't. C++ does not support object getters and setters like that.

(It is actually just about possible, but it really isn't worth it)

Answer (score 1):

1. There's various reasons to do this with setters and getters;

   - They provide better encapsulation; the actual values of a class' internal variables *should* be the responsibility of the class to set/get, *not* that of a user of an instance of a class. But there's different schools of thought on this subject.
   - They leave open the possibility of doing more than just setting/getting a value upon calling a setter/getter. For example,

     ```
     class circle
     {
         double _radius;
         double _perimeter;

     public:

         double getRadius() {return _radius;}

         void setRadius(double r) {
                 _radius = r;
                 _perimeter = 2*M_PI*r;
         } 
     };
     ```
2. Well, the way you indicate can be accomplshed simply by making `radius` a public variable :) However, consider this alternative approach:

   ```
   class circle
   {
   private: 
       double _radius;

   public:
       const double &radius;

       circle(double R)
           : radius(R)
           : radius(_radius)   
       {}

       void setRadius(double r) {
           _radius = r;
       } 
   };
   ```

   which would then be used like this:

   ```
   cout << a.radius;    // works
   a.radius = 3.2;      // produces error
   a.setRadius(3.2);    // works
   ```

   This approach has the benefit of concise, possibly more intuitive getters (i.e., use the actual variable name), more concise code (no need for countless virtually empty getters), and possibly even increased performance (a call to a getter function is slower than directly accessing a variable, although this depends on compiler optimization settings).

There's benefits and drawbacks to all methods mentioned here. In the end, it's *really* all up to the preferences of your team/employer.

Answer (score 0):

You use a getter and setter to achieve better encapsulation and to make it possible to change the underlying implementation in easier way.

About the second question: you can not do that. You will have to write a getter and setter method.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is the initializer way:

```
OCD::OCD ( ) : _number( 0 )
{
}
```

and the in body constructor way:

```
OCD::OCD ( size_t initial_value )
{
  _number = initial_value;
}
```

to access them inside the class instance just use the variable name:

```
  _number = value;
```

but if you have an global, local or argument variable with the same name, you can be specific like this:

```
  this->_number = value;
```

then from outside of the instance you can call it thus:

```
  // (that is if _number was public)
  std::cout << "ocd2._number    => " << ocd2._number << std::endl;
  std::cout << "ocd3p->_number  => " << ocd3p->_number << std::endl;
```

same goes for methods:

```
  std::cout << "ocd2.get( )     => " << ocd2.get() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "ocd3p->get( )   => " << ocd3p->get() << std::endl;
```

see my gist on the subject: https://gist.github.com/LaughingSun/7d2330ccff0777bec106